# How do you skip a Make target if a variable is empty?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following makefile

```
# If current commit is not part of a PR, the PULL_REQUEST_ID variable will be empty.
PULL_REQUEST_ID := $(shell git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head' | grep -F -f <(git rev-parse HEAD) | awk -F'/' '{print $3}')

# if PULL_REQUEST_ID is empty, I want 'make deploy-to-staging' to be no-op
.PHONY deploy-to-staging
deploy-to-staging: update-some-files apply-those-files-to-k8s
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're running `git ...` to produce the strings here, this seems to have nothing to do with Git. Why the [tag:git] tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your actions to deploy are prerequisites of a target, you can conditionally define those prerequisites, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
ifneq ($(PULL_REQUEST_ID),)
  deploy-to-staging:  update-some-files apply-those-files-to-k8s
endif

.PHONY: deploy-to-staging
deploy-to-staging:

.PHONY: update-some-files
update-some-files:
        echo Updating...

.PHONY: apply-those-files-to-k8s
apply-those-files-to-k8s:
        echo Applying...
```

Output:

```
$ make deploy-to-staging
make: Nothing to be done for 'deploy-to-staging'.

$ make deploy-to-staging PULL_REQUEST_ID=foo
echo Updating...
Updating...
echo Applying...
Applying...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the conditional directive `ifneq`.

```
deploy-to-staging: update-some-files apply-those-files-to-k8s
ifneq ($(PULL_REQUEST_ID),'')
        git push ...  # or whatever
else
        echo "Refusing to deploy non-pull-request to staging"
endif
```